# Close the Page on a Button click ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a "save & close" button where I need to close my page after saving the data. I have tried many ways, but none of them worked.

Code-behind:

```
protected void btnSaveClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Save();
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);
}
```

I need help closing the window.

Answer (score 2):

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/close) on the `close` method explains some of the limitations:

> This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the [`Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

In other words, this method simply won't work unless the window was opened with the `Window.open()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "close windows" in a Web application. Simply display a friendly message to the user as confirmation or a friendly error message, whichever the case may be. You can easily do this using three panels:

```
<asp:Panel id="formPanel" runat="server">
    <!-- Your form controls go here -->
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel id="confirmPanel" runat="server">
    <!-- Confirmation message -->
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel id="errorPanel" runat="server">
    <!-- Error message -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Just toggle the visible property of these panels at the appropriate points in your code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Here is the solution which fixed it.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["closewindow"] != null)
        closewindow = (bool)ViewState["closewindow"];

    if (closewindow)
    {
        closewindow = false;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Close_Window", "self.close();", true);
        //System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Close_Window", "self.close();", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string display = "Your dispaly";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);//this will dispaly the alert box


ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Close_Window", "self.close();", true);//this will close the page on button click
```

This Worked for me
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

This working for me, so I will recommend it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CloseBtn.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "self.close()");
}

protected void CloseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { self.close() }</script>");
}
```